# How to concatenate tensors after expanding dimension using Keras Functional API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to expand dimension:

```
import tensorflow as tf
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
inp = inp[..., tf.newaxis]
decoder_input = inp
output = tf.concat([inp, decoder_input], 1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, output )
```

But I get an error in the last line:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError Graph disconnected: cannot obtain
> value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
> at layer "tf_op_layer_strided_slice". The following previous layers
> were accessed without issue: []

Comment: I can't understand what you are expecting the model to do. Does the 'expand dimension' mean reshaping from shape (a,b)->(a,b,1) or something?

Comment: @krenerd yes, reshaping (a, b) -> (a, b, 1)

Comment: Use `tf.expand_dims` instead.

Comment: @today I tryed - not working as well

Comment: How did you use `tf.expand_dims`? Edit your question and add the code snippet. Probably you are still modifying the `inp` (which you shouldn't at all because that's the input of the model and should not be modified).

Comment: @today Thanks, I missed that I modified inp. I changed inp to x and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do? Seems you have a variable conflict. You are setting the `decoder_input` as a `reshape` layer instead of an `input` layer. Changing the name of the `reshape` layer fixes it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))

x = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((-1,1))(inp) #Use any of the 3
#x = tf.expand_dims(inp, axis=-1)
#x = inp[...,tf.newaxis]

decoder_input = inp
output = tf.concat([inp, decoder_input], 1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, output)

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "functional_8"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_7 (InputLayer)            [(None, 1)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_4 (TensorFlo [(None, 2)]          0           input_7[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_7[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting the model to reshape tensors from (a, b) -> (a, b, 1), you can use the `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` layer.

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
...
decoder_input = inp
output=tf.keras.layers.Reshape((a,b,1))(decoder_input ) #Replace (a,b,1) with your desired shape.
...
```